# When do Challenge notifications trigger?

Tags: borderlands-2

My previous question about scoped sniper kills counting for no-scope Challenges, seems like it could be explained by the notification being delayed.

For instance, if the notifications don't trigger while scoped.

Like if it works like this:

I hit the halfway point of the no-scope Challenge, then immediately use the scope and kill some more, the notification doesn't trigger until I un-scope, so it seems like scoped kills count for no-scope, but they don't, and I'm just confused?

Answer (score 1):

in theory, Challenge notifications will trigger the moment a criteria is met (eg. getting halfway through any Challenge, completing any Challenge, or whatever other criteria there may be). however, as with most other HUD elements--such as waypoint or mission changes, Duel or Trade requests, and so on--a sniper's scope overrides that HUD for its own. this will basically place the HUD elements "on hold" until the next available moment in gametime when the HUD can be updated, which would be (in theory) the few moments after your scope is put down.

Comment: IIRC, I've had the notification pop up while scoped, but I think you're at least close...